# python store lines from stdin directly to list objects

Tags: python

In researching the answer to this question here on stackoverflow, I've learned a lot of new things, but have so far been unable to close the deal.

My python process will be receiving one line of input via stdin, e.g.

```
[{'name':'ry', 'age':28}, {'name':'bo', 'age':11}, {'name':'ed', 'age':99}]
```

...and I'd like to be able to store this line directly to a list object that I can then iterate over, e.g.

```
for i in list:
    print i['age'], i['name']
```

...but I just cannot get this to work, whether I use `sys.stdin()` or the `fileinput` module. For example, even when I explicitly create a list with `x = list(stdin.readline())` it ends up making each character a separate item in the list, not parsing the text in the way I want it to. Anyway.. back to searching. (Thanks for reading.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bad way is to use `input`. However this is unsafe and the function has been removed in Python 3 (the function called `input` in Python 3 does the same as Python 2's `raw_input`).

A better way is to use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
import ast
x = ast.literal_eval(stdin.readline())
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/rVUG3)